# Fetching a part of a string using regex starting from a given word untill the end of the string(one that includes newlines)

Tags: python, regex, string

```
import re

stri = "Hello guys.\nHow are you doing?\nI hope you have sweet dreams tonight."
regex = re.compile("guys[.\n]*$")

print regex.findall(stri)
```

I know `.` in regex can be any character except a newline, `[xy]` means either x or y, `*` after a character means any number of that character and `$` denotes the end of the string. So why does `"guys[.\n]*$"` not give me `"guys.\nHow are you doing?\nI hope you have sweet dreams tonight."`?

Comment: By the way, if you use the flag `re.DOTALL` then the dot will match newlines also(and you can avoid using the character class at all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You put the period in a character class, where it is the *one* place it will just match a `.` character and nothing else. `[...]` means any *literal* character contained in that class.

You want to use the [`re.DOTALL` configuration constant](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) instead:

```
regex = re.compile("guys.*$", re.DOTALL)
```

Alternatively, you should keep the `.` outside of the character class and use it in a group with the `\n` newline:

```
regex = re.compile("guys(?:.|\n)*$")
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> stri = "Hello guys.\nHow are you doing?\nI hope you have sweet dreams tonight."
>>> regex = re.compile("guys.*$", re.DOTALL)
>>> print regex.findall(stri)
['guys.\nHow are you doing?\nI hope you have sweet dreams tonight.']
```

Answer (score 2):

Martijn's answer gives a good explanation for the behavior you are seeing.  As an alternative to the `re.DOTALL` or `(?:.\n)` option, you can use something like the following:

```
regex = re.compile(r"guys[\s\S]*$")
```

Since `\s` means "all whitespace" and `\S` means "anything but whitespace", putting them in a character class together will allow to match any character including newlines.

Answer (score 0):

<s>use `re.MULLTILINE`  and you should match over lines...</s>

```
>>> regex = re.compile("guys.*",re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
>>> regex.findall(stri)
['guys.\nHow are you doing?\nI hope you have sweet dreams tonight.']
```

/EDIT :As martjin points out I am wrong about multi-line

```
>>> regex = re.compile("guys.*",re.DOTALL)
>>> regex.findall(stri)
['guys.\nHow are you doing?\nI hope you have sweet dreams tonight.']
```

Comment: `re.MULTILINE` only applies to where the `^` and `$` start and end anchors attach to.

Comment: yeah ok ... Ive been using that wrong for a while (thanks for that :) always like learning something new